# Is it safe to define multiple descriptors in srcset?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design

I need to store both width and height of images (of each size) to parse them later via JS. And I use syntax that defines both `w` and `h` descriptors:

```
<img srcset="small.jpg 600w 400h, 
          medium.jpg 1024w 500h,
          large.jpg 1600w 900h"
  alt="">
```

Is syntax with both `w` and `h` descriptors valid? I tested it in a few browsers, and it seems to work, but I'm not sure how future friendly it is. Or should I just store height somewhere else, e.g.:

```
<img srcset="small.jpg 600w, 
          medium.jpg 1024w,
          large.jpg 1600w"
  data-my-sizes="600x400 1024x500 1600x900"
  alt="">
```

Comment: Height is [not mentioned](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#attr-img-srcset) at all in the spec, so I would say it is not safe to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Co-author of the `<picture>` spec here.

Technically safe, only because we explicitly allow the `h` descriptor for future compat.  As long as you're using it correctly (for the actual height, same as `w`) you should be safe when we eventually turn on support for height-based selection.

But you can't do anything else; any unrecognized descriptors (anything but `x`, `w`, or `h`) cause the candidate to get thrown out.

Answer (score 2):

No `srcset` implementation takes height into account currently, but it *is* part of the long-term plan—and as that appears, those `h` descriptors could end up influencing which source is shown. If the JS behavior you’re writing is meant to match how a native implementation would handle `h` descriptors, I’d go that route but proceed with caution—there’s no way of saying how the spec/implementations might play out someday. If not, I’d definitely stick with a `data-` attribute.

One little aside: you’ll need a `sizes` on there. Behavior still defaults to `100vw` in the event that the attribute is omitted, but it is required for validation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the h descriptor is mentioned in the spec as the "future-compat-h" descriptor. It was added to the parsing rules so that browsers, which only do support the width descriptor won't fail as soon as the h descriptor is specified and used by developers.

Which means it is save to use, but currently not supported by any browser (the exact way how to write the sizes attribute for height constrained respimages isn't even specified). But be aware picturefill 2.x does not parse such a `srcset` string correctly and you should use either:

- [picturefill 3.0](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/tree/afarkas-pf3-proposal/dist)
- [respimage](https://github.com/aFarkas/respimage)